# Excel questions. IF OR? formula?

Tags: excel-formula, formulas

I have four columns, 2 headings.

```
Heading 1 - Lease
b2 - # of sedans 
c2 - $800

Heading 2 - Purchase
d2 - # of SUVs
e2- $800
```

Can I have a formula where:

- if a number is entered in b2 then you will only multiply b2*c2 and not by e2
- Or if a number is entered in d2 it'll only multiply d2*e2.

All is one row which I find complicated. The total will be in F2.

Comment: what if a number is in both b2 and d2?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside what to do if both `B2` and `D2` are not blank, try this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",D2*E2),B2*C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version:
You could enter one number at a time and leave either B2 or D2 blank to get what you want.

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2*C2,IF(D2<>"",D2*E2))
```

This will help, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott has pointed out, there may be both sedan leases and suv purchases.

```
=if(count(b2, d2), b2*c2+d2*e2, "")
```